# How to create a comma seperated list from multiple items in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-template

At my angular application, I'm trying to create a comma separated list of values I've got from my API response.

The API response looks like this:

```json
    {
       "release_date":"2012-03-14",
       "some_relation":[
          {
             "id":"2604ebbf-4eb5-46e3-89d8-ab4e8ecc8275",
             "name":"ABC"
          },
          {
             "id":"5267a0c6-9423-4e28-a413-133cc3435612",
             "name":"DEF"
          },
          {
             "id":"13d1454a-fc0e-457c-9f8e-9a9952984d8c",
             "name":"GHI"
          }
       ],
    }
```

`some_relation` in nested, so I created an interface for this logic to work:

```
    export interface SomeResponse {
        some_relation: some[];
    }

    export interface some {
      id: string;
      name: string;
    }
```

At my html template, I now do this:

```html
      <div *ngFor="let some of some_response.some_relation">
        <small>{{ some.name }}</small>
      </div>
```

Which returns the following output:

ABC

DEF

GHI

Instead of multiple lines outputted, I would like to have it that way:

```
ABC, DEF, GHI
```

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

- Change `div` for `span` so it would not put each item in new line
- Add `,` only if it's not the **last** item

```html
<span *ngFor="let item of some_response.some_relation; let last = last">
  <small>{{ item.name }}</small><span *ngIf="!last">, </span>
</span>
```

Comment: For some reason I don't get join and item to resolve :( any idea? Besides, does this also cut off the last comma?

Comment: @KaydeeDunlop yes... you won't get comma at the end and this will work fine

Comment: @NeNaD:
```Unresolved function or method join()``` and also ```Binding expression cannot contain assignments``` for ```=>``` I'm not saying your answer is wrong but not working for me :(

Comment: I updated my answer with another solution. Can you try it again?

Comment: Much better, now it works like a charm :D Thank you very much dude

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using *ngFor on division tag instead of small tag and it is creating 3 division with a small tag in each division. Division is a block element and each division is rendered on the next line. Try doing something like this for single line rendering:

```
<small *ngFor="let some of some_response.some_relation" >
{{ some.name }} 
</small>
```

Edit: Since you want the comma in between you can use this:

```
<small> 
{{ some_response.some_relation.reduce((total, obj, index) => index? total + ", " + obj.name: obj.name, "") }} 
</small>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the whole comma separation is missing in your answer. But at least I now have a single line :D

Comment: @KaydeeDunlop - My bad, I did not notice the comma. I have added an alternative solution with commas in between in the recent edit.